# Differentiation of log

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$ln(2y+1) = xe^y$

How would you differentiate this??

I don't know how to arrange it in terms of y to start with. Could you please help? I think I can start differentiating once the equation is arranged in terms of y.

Answer (score 1):

$x=e^{-y}\ln \left( 2y+1 \right)$

Then find $\frac{dx}{dy}$ and: $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dy}}$$

Comment: or you could do implicit differentiation if you know how

Answer (score 1):

$$\log(2y+1) = xe^y$$
Let's assume $y$ is a function of $x$ and apply implicit differentiation
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\log(2y+1)) = \frac{d}{dx}(xe^y)$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{2 y'}{2y+1} = e^yxy'+e^y$$
$$\Rightarrow 2y' = (2y+1)(e^yxy'+e^y)$$
$$\Rightarrow 2y' = 2ye^yxy'+e^yxy'+(2y+1)(e^y)$$
$$\Rightarrow y'(2-2ye^yx-e^yx) = (2y+1)(e^y)$$
$$\Rightarrow y' = \frac{(2y+1)(e^y)}{(2-2ye^yx-e^yx)}$$
You can probably clean this up a lot, but you now have the derivative singled out (as desired).